# Anonymous access to SVN server

Tags: svn

I am using SVN via apache2. I have Ubuntu as OS. Below are my configurations:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /var/lib/svn

  # I have tried basic as well
  AuthName "Subversion repository"
  AuthType Digest
  AuthUserFile /etc/dav_svn.passwd

<IfModule mod_authz_svn.c>
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/svn_access_control
</IfModule>

  <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    Require valid-user
  </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Is there a way to allow only registered users to view/checkout svn? I don't want anonymous users to access.

I can still access the SVN via browser and SVN client. I tried to remove the tag  "`<LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>`" but then Apache gives "Internal Server Error".

```
[Tue Oct 29 15:06:16 2013] [crit] [client [IP]] configuration error:  couldn't check user.  Check your authn provider!: /svn/repo1/, referer: http://[IP]
```

I am totally novice to Linux :(

Thanks

Comment: What does error.log say?

Comment: There is nothing in the log file. I looked at this file "/var/log/apache2/access.log"

Comment: So there's no `error.log` in that same folder? There should be if it's tossing internal errors...access.log won't help.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about this file. yes it is there. It says: [Tue Oct 29 15:06:16 2013] [crit] [client [IP]] configuration error:  couldn't check user.  Check your authn provider!: /svn/repo1/, referer: http://[IP]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the digest module.

Find this line in your `apache2.conf` (or `httpd.conf`) and uncomment:

`LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so`

If you can't find it, add it to the existing list of LoadModule lines.

Comment: I couldn't find digest so I made the mode to "basic". It is working now. Weird :p Thanks for the help :) Is basic mode secure?

Comment: Basic/digest mode are both insecure over http since the password is transmitted in plaintext. The only difference is how the passwords are generated (`htpasswd` versus `htdigest`).